# I am trying to implement refreshCountryList , which should return countryList(array of objects) variable which contains all countries

Tags: angular, list, search, subscribe

**Country.component.ts**

```
 countryList :any;
  searchvalue : string = "" ;

  constructor( private service : SharedService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshCountryList();
  }
  
  refreshCountryList(){
    this.service.getCountryList().subscribe(data=>{ this.countryList = data 
      console.log("countryList inside subscribe :",this.countryList ) ;
    });
    console.log( "list outside subscribe :" , this.countryList);
  }
```

**shared.service.ts**

```
export class SharedService {

  readonly APIUrl = "https://localhost:44383/api/CountryApi/";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  getCountryList(){
    return this.http.get(this.APIUrl + 'listcountry');
  }


}
```

I couldn't get countryList value outside the subscribe, the scope resides only inside subscribe.

What can I do for getting the Value outside subscribe?

Comment: You want data to be shared everywhere? If so, on subscribe store it in the same service file in a variable and use that.

Comment: still not getting **countryList** . could you more specific

Comment: I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular synchronously executes the code. `subscribe()` actually gets executed at the last after the execution of all synchronous codes. So this line gets executed first before subscribe is called.

```
console.log( "list outside subscribe :" , this.countryList);
```

However, if you just want to see the output you can put a JSON pipe on the HTML side and see it in the view.

```
<pre> <div [innerHTML]="this.countryList | json"></div> >/pre>
```

Another method is to store the data and call a method to check if data is available which in turn can be used to put logic in it.

```
countryList :any;
searchvalue : string = "" ;

constructor( private service : SharedService) { }
  
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.refreshCountryList();
}
  
mapData(){
  console.log(this.countryList);
}

refreshCountryList(){
  this.service.getCountryList().subscribe((data)=>{
    if(!data) return;
    this.countryList = data;
    console.log("countryList inside subscribe :",this.countryList ) ;
    this.mapData();
  });
  console.log( "list outside subscribe :" , this.countryList);
}
```